What would be the best filters to put in a table?
I'm working for an ATS (Applicant tracking system) and we have tables to organize the information about the candidates and the processes better. This ATS has a vertical menu on the left and plenty of buttons, elements, everywhere. Now, what is the most efficient filter to put for tables with +20 categories?
I'm thinking of something similar to Notion where you can collapse it to make the space more efficient. But I don't know if there is a better option. (I don't think it's a good idea a filter on the side because of the vertical menu and the table in general, it reduces the space even more).
